# Is it optional to import Java packages in Scala?

Tags: scala

I find the following `Scala` program works OK without importing "`java.lang.Thread`" (`Scala` version is `2.11.6`):

```
object ThreadsMain extends App {
    val t: Thread = Thread.currentThread()
    val name = t.getName()
    println(s"$name")
}
```

The output is:

```
Main
```

Does it mean there is no need to including `Java` packages in `Scala` program explicitly? Or are there some rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained on the [Scala homepage](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-for-java-programmers.html#interaction-with-java) the imports from `java.lang` are done automatically whereas all other classes have to be imported explicitly.